# Plugin for communication protocols in browser(s)

Tags: javascript, ajax, plugin, websocket

I would like to get some feedback from the community regarding a plugin I recently moved from requiring jQuery to a stand alone JS implementation. It is meant to handle browser communication protocols such as XHR, XDR, WS & WSS without a lot of fuss.

The project can also be found @ [comm.js](https://github.com/jas-/comm.js).

```
/**
 * Description: Handles AJAX, XDR, WS & WSS protocols
 *
 * Fork me @ https://www.github.com/jas-/comm.js
 *
 * Author: Jason Gerfen <jason.gerfen@gmail.com>
 * License: GPL (see LICENSE)
 */

(function(window, undefined){

  'use strict';

  var comm = comm || function(o){

        /**
         * @object defaults
         * @abstract Default set of options for plug-in
         *
         * @param {String} appID Unique identifier
         * @param {String} url Specified URL param
         * @param {Mixed} data String/Boolean/Object
         * @param {Boolean} debug Enable or disable debugging options
         * @param {Object} bind Element to which this plug-in is bound
         * @param {Boolean} async Default to async communication
         * @param {String} method Method of communication (GET, PUT, POST, DELETE)
         * @param {Function} callback Callback function for success
         * @param {Object} precallback Callback prior to send
         * @param {Object} errcallback Callback on errors
         */
        var defaults = {
            appID: 'comm.js',
            url: '',
            data: false,
            debug: false,
            async: true,
            method: 'get',
            logID: '',
            callback: function(){},
            precallback: function(){},
            errcallback: function(){}
        };

        /**
         * @method _setup
         * @scope private
         * @abstract Initial setup routines
         */
        var _setup = _setup || {

            /**
             * @function save
             * @scope private
             * @abstract Primary initialization of window.crypto API
             *
             * @param {Object} o Plug-in option object
             * @returns {Boolean} true/false
             */
            init: function(o){
                this.go(o);
            },

            /**
             * @function go
             * @scope private
             * @abstract Initializes request if data present
             *
             * @param {Object} o Plug-in option object
             * @returns {Object}
             */
            go: function(o){
                if (_comm.online()){
                    _comm.decide(o, o.url);
                } else {
                    return '{error:"Network connectivity not present"}';
                }
                return o.data;
            }
        };

        /**
         * @method _comm
         * @scope private
         * @abstract Communication methods
         */
        var _comm = _comm || {

            /**
             * @function online
             * @scope private
             * @abstract Detect current connection status
             *
             * @returns {Boolean}
             */
            online: function(){
                return navigator.onLine;
            },

            /**
             * @function retry
             * @scope private
             * @abstract Attempts to send any non-sent requests when online status is true
             *
             * @param {Object} o Application defaults
             * @param {Object} d JSON object of key/values to send to server
             * @param {String} c Command to send to remote storage proxy service
             * @param {String} e The remote protocol to execute
             *
             * @returns {Boolean}
             */
            retry: function(o, d, c){
                var _c = 10, _i = 0;
                var id = setInterval(function(o, d, c){
                    (this.online) ? this.decide(o, d, c) : false;
                }, 3600);
                clearInterval(id);
                return true;
            },

            /**
             * @function decide
             * @scope private
             * @abstract Determine mode of communication based on browser type and options
             *
             * @param {Object} o Application defaults
             * @param {Object} d JSON object of key/values to send to server
             * @param {String} c Command to send to remote storage proxy service
             *
             * @returns {Function}
             */
            decide: function(o, c){
                var _reg = new RegExp(document.location.href);

                if ((/msie/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) && (/^(http|https):\/\//i.test(o.url)) &&
                        (!_reg.test(o.url))) {
                    return (this.online) ? this.xdr(o, o.data, c) : this.retry(o, o.data, c);
                }

                if (/^(ws|wss):\/\//i.test(o.url)) {
                    return (this.online) ? this.websocket(o, o.data, c) : this.retry(o, o.data, c);
                }

                return (this.online) ? this.ajax(o, o.data, c) : this.retry(o, o.data, c);
            },

            /**
             * @function websocket
             * @scope private
             * @abstract Perform get/send of remote objects using websockets
             *
             * @param {Object} o Application defaults
             * @param {Object} d JSON object of key/values to send to server
             *
             * @returns {String|Object}
             */
            websocket: function(o){
                var _r = false
                    ,   socket = new WebSocket(o.url);

                (o.debug) ? _log.debug(o.logID, '_comm.websocket: Status: '+socket.readyState) : false;

                socket.onopen = function() {
                    try {
                        socket.send(o.data);
                        (o.debug) ? _log.debug(o.logID, '_comm.websocket: Sent: '+o.data) : false;
                    } catch(exception) {
                        _log.error(o.logID, '_comm.websocket: Error => '+exception);
                    }
                }

                socket.onmessage = function(msg) {
                    (o.debug) ? _log.debug(o.logID, '_comm.websocket: Receieved: '+msg.data) : false;
                    _r = msg.data;
                    socket.close();
                }

                socket.onclose = function() {
                    (o.debug) ? _log.debug(o.logID, '_comm.websocket: Status: '+socket.readyState) : false;
                }

                return _r;
            },

            /**
             * @function xdr
             * @scope private
             * @abstract Perform get/send of remote objects using MS XDR
             *
             * @param {Object} o Application defaults
             * @param {Object} d JSON object of key/values to send to server
             * @param {String} c Command to send to remote storage proxy service (Save|Retrieve)
             *
             * @returns {String|Object}
             */
            xdr: function(o, d, c){
                var _r = false;

                if (!window.XDomainRequest) {
                    _log.error(o.logID, '_comm.xdr: Error => The XDR functionality for your browser was not found.');
                    return false;
                }

                var xdr = new XDomainRequest();
                xdr.timeout = 100;
                xdr.open('post', o.url+'?cmd='+c);

                xdr.onsuccess = function(response){
                    (o.debug) ? _log.debug(o.logID, '_libs.xdr: '+xdr.responseText) : false;
                    _r = xdr.responseText;
                };

                xdr.onerror = function(exception){
                    _log.error(o.logID, '_libs.xdr: Error => '+exception);
                };

                xdr.send(d);

                return _r;
            },

            /**
             * @function ajax
             * @scope private
             * @abstract Perform get/send of remote objects
             *
             * @param {Object} o Application defaults
             * @param {Object} d JSON object of key/values to send to server
             * @param {String} c Command to send to remote storage proxy service (Save|Retrieve)
             *
             * @returns {String|Object}
             */
            ajax: function(o, d, c){
                var _r = false
                    , _h = false
                    , _xhr = false
                    ,   _reg = new RegExp(document.location.href);

                function _response(data) {
                    _r = data.responseText;
                }

                function _error(err) {
                    _r = err.status;
                }

                function _handler() {
                    if (this.readyState == this.DONE && this.status == 200) {
                        _response(this.responseText);
                    }
                }

                function _headers(o) {
                    if (!_reg.test(o.url))
                        _xhr.withCredentials = true;

                    ((o.precallback) && (/function/.test(typeof(o.precallback)))) ?
                        o.precallback(this) : false;

                    (o.debug) ?
                        _log.debug(o.logID, '_comm.ajax: Set request headers') :
                        false;
                }

                _xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                _xhr.onreadystatechange = _handler;
                _xhr.open(o.method, o.url, o.async);
                _headers(o);
                _xhr.send(/post|put/i.test(o.method)?o.data:null);

                return _r;
            }
        }

        /**
         * @method _libs
         * @scope private
         * @abstract Miscellaneous helper libraries
         */
        var _libs = _libs || {

      /**
         * @function merge
         * @scope private
         * @abstract Perform preliminary option/default object merge
         *
         * @param {Object} o Plug-in option object
         * @param {Object} d Default plug-in option object
       *
         * @returns {Object}
         */
        merge: function(d, o){
                d = d || {};

            for (var p in d) {
          if (d.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
            o[p] = (/object/.test(typeof(d[p]))) ?
                            this.merge(o[p], d[p]) : d[p];
          }
          o[p] = d[p];
        }

                o.logID = o.appID;

        (o.debug) ? _log.debug(o.logID, '_libs.merge: Merged options') : false;

        return o;
        }
        };

        /**
         * @method _log
         * @scope private
         * @abstract Logging methods for
         *  - debug
         *  - info
         *  - warn
         *  - error
         */
        var _log = _log || {

            /**
             * @function debug
             * @scope private
             * @abstract Debugging _log function
             *
             * @param {String} i The application ID associated with implementation
             * @param {String} t The message string to be rendered
             */
            debug: function(i, t){
                (/function/i.test(typeof(console.debug))) ?
                    console.debug('['+i+'] (DEBUG) '+t) : false;
            },

            /**
             * @function info
             * @scope private
             * @abstract Information _log function
             *
             * @param {String} i The application ID associated with implementation
             * @param {String} t The message string to be rendered
             */
            info: function(i, t){
                (/function/i.test(typeof(console.info))) ?
                    console.info('['+i+'] (DEBUG) '+t) : false;
            },

            /**
             * @function warn
             * @scope private
             * @abstract Warning _log function
             *
             * @param {String} i The application ID associated with implementation
             * @param {String} t The message string to be rendered
             */
            warn: function(i, t){
                (/function/i.test(typeof(console.warn))) ?
                    console.warn('['+i+'] (DEBUG) '+t) : false;
            },

            /**
             * @function error
             * @scope private
             * @abstract Error _log function
             *
             * @param {String} i The application ID associated with implementation
             * @param {String} t The message string to be rendered
             */
            error: function(i, t){
                (/function/i.test(typeof(console.error))) ?
                    console.error('['+i+'] (DEBUG) '+t) : false;
            }
        };

        /**
         * @function init
         * @scope public
         * @abstract
         */
        var init = function(){

            /* Merge user supplied options with defaults */
            var opts = _libs.merge(o, defaults);

            /* Initialize setup */
            if (!_setup.init(opts)) {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }();

    }

    /* comm.js, do work */
    window.comm = comm;

})(window);
```

Comment: I have applied the suggestions, removed some unnecessary functionality while adding some needed functionality which can be seen on the project page @ https://github.com/jas-/comm.js.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting question,

2 upfront general notes first:

- Run your code through JsHint.com, there are a ton of little things you could fix
- Run your code through a beautifier, there are a ton of inconsistencies

Also, consider the following

- You have too many 1 letter variable `s`,`i`,`o`,`x`,`y`,`e` are pretty well understood, but for the rest you should have meaningful names
- If you had meaningful names, and good function names, then your comments would not have to be so extensive
- You use `_` for private stuff, I agree with Crockford, either you make it private (with an IIFE or other means) or you dont and then you drop the underscore.
- `@abstract Primary initialization of window.crypto API` <- Wut?
- You seem to depend on `this.online` a number of times, did you intend to call `this.online()` ?
- In `retry()` you have `3600` and `10` as magical, unnamed constants
- You should use your comments as a guide for naming, for this comment:

  ```
  @abstract Determine mode of communication based on browser type and option
  ```

  I would expect the function to be called something like `determineCommunicationMode`, not `decide`. Especially since you call `decide` only twice
- Ternary statements, I love them, but you have to know that in general an `if` statement is preferred if there is no `else` block ( Ternary <-> three )
- In `xdr: function(o, d, c){`, you use only `c` once here:

  ```
  xdr.open('post', o.url+'?cmd='+c);
  ```

  I would much rather have `xdr.open( 'post', o.url );` and let the caller take care of concatenating the command, otherwise this is a bit hard coded..
- One more hardcoded constant `100` in `xdr`
- In `ajax` you could simply do

  ```
      ajax: function(o, d, c){
          var r = false
              , xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
              , reg = new RegExp(document.location.href);
  ```

  because

  - `_h` is not used anywhere
  - underscores are silly here, the variables are scoped to the function
  - first setting `xhr` to `false` and then to `new XMLHttpRequest();` does not make sense
  - Comma's first is a movement I respect, but expect some slamming over that choice
  - `/function/.test(typeof(o.precallback))` <- This is too [Yoda-esque](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yoda_conditions) in my mind

Furthermore, in the log object, you check for the type of `error`, `debug` etc. every single instead of once up front. Also, you are not checking whether console actually exists. I would have a `init` function which checks for console and it's function and provides a dummy implementation in case those are missing.

Comment: This is just what I was hoping for.